# Scope variable is not updating value from timeout function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to update a scope variables and counter value from a timeout function but somehow view is not updating. Here is my code:

```
var countDown = 30, timer;
         if (status.statusCode="401") {
                    $scope.showCounter = true;
                    $scope.disabledLoginBtn = true;
                    $scope.error = 'login.user.block.text';
                    $log.info("countDownStart: ");
                    _countDowner();

                }

    function _countDowner() {
            if (countDown <= 0) {
                countDown = 0;
                $scope.disabledLoginBtn = false;
                $scope.showCounter = false;
                $scope.error = null;
                $timeout.cancel(timer);
                $log.info("counter: finish ");
                return;
            } else {
                countDown--;
                $scope.countDown_text = countDown + " Second";
                $log.info($scope.countDown_text);
                timer = $timeout(_countDowner, 1000);
            }
        }
```

When `status.statusCode="401"` condition meet this counter start and i can see that count down print a value in a console but somehow all scope variables like `$scope.showCounter, $scope.disabledLoginBtn $scope.error` are not updating on a view. I am bit confused why this is happening. Can someone tell me a reason.

Comment: what does `_countDowStarter()` function do?

Comment: what value is "countDown ", is negative <0?

Comment: It was function name mistake in a code, i updated it now

Comment: Add a fiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Is this in a controller or a service? Maybe you're modifying the wrong scope.

Comment: It seems to be working fine with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WGFu7lvUyUk1TEuDzQGT). Can you check what is missing?